# Python gcloud clusters get-credentials returns permission error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, subprocess, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-python-client

I'm working on a Python(3.6) project in which I have implemented Google cloud apis, I have setup credentials for Google Cloud via service account.
Here's what I have tried:

> Obtain Credentials:

```
def prepare_credentials(cred_file):
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(cred_file)
    return credentials
```

And then I have tried to run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone $ZONE --project $PROJECT`
as below:

> Run gcloud command via Python's Subprocess:

```
print(subprocess.call(
            'gcloud container clusters get-credentials ' + data['cluster_name'] + ' --zone '
            + data['zone_region']
            + ' --project ' + data['project_id'],
            shell=True))
```

it returns this error:

> Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/brain-183103/zones/europe-west1-d/clusters/numpy".
>
> 1
>
> W0629 04:12:00.776926    2222 factory_object_mapping.go:423] Failed to download OpenAPI (Get https://104.197.10.169/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1: dial tcp 104.197.10.169:443: i/o timeout), falling back to swagger
>   Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 104.197.10.169:443: i/o timeout

Service Account credentials are working well as I'm using these credentials for various other Google Cloud API calls and also I have set the `owner` permission to the project for this service_account.

Have I configured something wrong?

Help me, please!

Thank You,
Abdul

Comment: Hi @NitishkumarSingh, how can I do that? please!

Comment: it couldn't solve the issue!

Comment: Ohh my bad, i just saw you are actually working with containers. What are the container permission you have assigned to your service account? Refer link for more info https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam

Comment: I have set up service account role as `owner`.

Comment: Do I still need to add other roles/permissions?

Comment: `Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/brain-183103/zones /europe-west1-d/clusters/numpy"` this line is indicating that you don't have proper permission configured

Comment: I have created a new service account and add these roles: `Owner, Container Analysis Admin, Kubernetes Engine Developer, Kubernetes Engine Admin, Cloud Build Service Account` but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Other then these roles I couldn't find any Container OR Cluster related role.

Comment: these permission should be enough

Comment: I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34395) with the same error `code 403` and it was resolved by creating a new service account/key with different name since names are cached. Try, the solution suggested in the Github post and see if it helps resolves the issue for you. Since this is related to Kubenetes gcloud container engine, it seems like the authentication process is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work.

Python's `subprocess` provides a way to run e.g. `gcloud` commands and communicate between your Python process and e.g. `gcloud` using I/O (and error) pipes.

In your code, you show the creation of a Python `credential` object representing your service account *and* then your run `gcloud` in a sub-process. There's no credential sharing between these two processes and so `gcloud` is using whatever it has in context, probably the user's `$HOME/.config/gcloud`.

It's further complicated by the fact that `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` performs a bunch of *magic* with the user's `gcloud` credentials and the cluster specified, to configure `$HOME/.kube/config` so that subsequent kubectl commands authenticate using Open ID Connect.

Given that you're using a service account, I assume, because this requires distributing the service account's key to authenticate, that you don't intend to have many|dynamic copies of your code performing this authentication. If that's correct, then you may wish to consider performing the `gcloud container cluster get-credentials` outside of (and before) your Python code (either manually or via a shell script) and then (once you have a correctly configured `$HOME/.kube/config` for your cluster), use [Kubernetes' Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) (!) to perform whatever work you'd like to do on the cluster.

Although not a solution to this problem specifically, I recommend you use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) (ADCs) in your code. ADCs result in one way to authenticate regardless of whether your code runs off-or-on Google Cloud Platform and regardless of whether you use user or service accounts.

Here's a Python sample using the Cloud Client Library and Application Default Credentials. The library does *not* (appear) to solve the challenge in effectively converting GCP service account credentials into credentials (via ~/.kube/config) that you may use to access the Kubernetes cluster. But, you can apply operations to clusters using this library:

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-container==0.1.1
```

python.py:

```
from google.cloud import container_v1

client = container_v1.ClusterManagerClient()

project_id = "[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]"
zone = "[[YOUR-ZONE]]"

cluster_id = "[[YOUR-CLUSTER-ID]]"

cluster = {
   "name": cluster_id,
    "initial_node_count": 1,
    "master_auth":{
      #"username": "admin",
      "client_certificate_config": {
      },
    },
    #logging_service = "logging.googleapis.com",
    #monitoring_service = "monitoring.googleapis.com",
    "initial_cluster_version": "1.10.5-gke.3",
}
response = client.create_cluster(project_id, zone, cluster)

response = client.list_clusters(project_id, zone)

response = client.delete_cluster(project_id, zone, cluster_id)
```

NB username is not present in the dict to disable username|password. `client_certificate_config` is empty (`{}`) to *not* issue a client cert. You may wish to change these. I think there's a bug in the JSON response of the create cluster too that I'll report.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, I have to automate the entire process, so I can't leave anything on manual.

Comment: There's a Google-provided Python SDK that includes Kubernetes Engine (aka Container Engine) API. I've not used it. If you're interested, I will try the SDK for you? There's a method (the documentation is buggy) here (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/container/gapic/v1/api.html) that may address your need. See also the link (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5008) HTH